# Android app closes unexpectedly and never shows

Tags: android, kotlin

I am detecting common gestures using the Android gesture detector
class but the app closes unexpectedly with the message "common gestures keeps stopping" and never shows.

I am expecting the activity to open and I can capture the common gestures.

`minSdk = 26`,
`targetSdk = 33`,
`compileSdk = 34`,
`Emulator: Pixel 4 API 26` (`Android 8 (Oreo)`)

Code Implementation:

```kotlin
package com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat
import com.ebookfrenzy.commongestures.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), 
GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

    var gDetector: GestureDetectorCompat? = null

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        
        val mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, "hola", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
        mySnackbar.show()

        this.gDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, this)
        gDetector?.setOnDoubleTapListener(this)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        this.gDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onDown"
        return true
    }

    override fun onFling(
        event1: MotionEvent?,
        event2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onFling"
        return true
    }

    override fun onLongPress(event: MotionEvent) {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onLongPress"
    }

    override fun onScroll(
        e1: MotionEvent?,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        distanceX: Float,
        distanceY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onScroll"
        return true
    }

    override fun onShowPress(event: MotionEvent) {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onShowPress"
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onSingleTapUp"
        return true
    }

    override fun onDoubleTap(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onDoubleTap"
        return true
    }

    override fun onDoubleTapEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onDoubleTapEvent"
        return true
    }

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        binding.gestureStatusText.text = "onSingleTapConfirmed"
        return true
    }
}
```

I am detecting common gestures using the Android gesture detector
class but the app closes unexpectedly with the message "common gestures keeps stopping" and never shows.

I am expecting the activity to open and I can capture the common gestures.

[Log cat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFtvE.jpg)

Comment: If the app is crashing, there's a stack trace in logcat. What is the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that a activity cannot be abstract. Problem solved, thaks all.